# Dynamic Denominator in Power BI for Date Drill Down

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to be able to answer the following question:

What is Hardware Market Share in 2015 and 2016 and 2017? [image]

Here is the formula I am using for Market Share:

```
Market Share = divide(CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Number of Sales])), Calculate(sum(Sheet1[Number of Sales]), all(Sheet1)))
```

With the current Market Share formula, I cannot tell what Market Share was for Hardware for 2015, all I know is Market Share for Hardware in 2015 is 19% of overall Market Share. I don't want overall Market Share.

I want to have a dynamic denominator reflecting the x-axis.

Here is the desired picture:

[image]

See how the Y Axis totals 100% as opposed to the first picture is ~ 30%.

I'm unsure wear to begin, any directed towards a related problem will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the answer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Have-Market-Share-equal-100-with-every-type-of-Date-Drill-Down/td-p/175895)

I posted on the Microsoft forum as well. There is a visual called 100% stacked bar chart which will do exactly what I was requesting.

Here is what the visual icon looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dividing by the SUM of all rows, only divide by the sum of rows that have the same year.

Try this:

```
Market Share = divide(CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Number of Sales])), Calculate(sum(Sheet1[Number of Sales]), FILTER(Sheet1, [Year]=EARLIER([Year]))))
```

The trick is on the filter: `FILTER(Sheet1, [Year]=EARLIER([Year]))`

Comment: No quite -- tried similar, the issue is when I drill down, I'll get month's as a subset of the Year. I posted in Microsoft's form, and got the answer: [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Have-Market-Share-equal-100-with-every-type-of-Date-Drill-Down/m-p/177130/highlight/false#M77432)